# How to rename a mysql table and column in a single query?

Tags: mysql, rename, alter

I'm writing a mysql workbench.  I'd like to update a table and columns with a single query.  Would I need to use a nested query or is what I'm trying to do not possible?

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable CHANGE id id2 int; // works

ALTER TABLE MyTable TO|RENAME MyTable2 CHANGE id id2 int; // fails
```

Comment: Why not use two seperate queries?

Comment: I understand I can do it with 2 queries, and I understand the speed difference would be negligible.  I am curious if this is possible.

Comment: At the end of the day, it just took a comma before the "CHANGE":

  ALTER TABLE MyTable RENAME MyTable2, CHANGE id id2 int;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can make multiple changes in one ALTER TABLE statement.

The syntax reference shows:

> ```
> ALTER TABLE tbl_name
>     [alter_option [, alter_option] ...]
>     [partition_options]
> ```

Note the optional additional `alter_option` separated by comma.

Demo:

```
mysql> create table mytable (id serial primary key, x int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> alter table mytable rename column x to y, rename as myothertable;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: Thankyou very much!